# How to plot several curves on one graph with defined function in R?

Tags: r, plot, curve

I need to plot a couple of curves on one graph. I've got trajectories of Brownian simulation which I got from the function:

```
brownian <- function(T,N){
  alpha=0
  sigma=1
  
  delta_t=T/N
  
  t=seq(0,T,by=delta_t)
  #x=c(0,alpha*delta_t+sigma*sqrt(delta_t)*rnorm(N,mean=0,sd=1))
  x=c(0,alpha*delta_t+sqrt(delta_t)*rnorm(N,mean=0,sd=1))
  Xt=cumsum(x)
  plot(t,Xt,type='l',col = rep(1:3, each = 10),xlab="t=[0,T]",ylab = "B(t,ω)")
}
```

For example for brownian(1,1000) I get:

[image]

And for brownian(10,1000) I get:

[image]

As you can see I get black graphs. I have to plot these trajectories on one graph (every trajectory should have different color). When it takes several trajectories, it should look like:

[image]

Do you have any advices how can I plot these curves on one graph and each curve has different color?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could do this pretty easily by modifying the function and using `ggplot()` to make the graph.  The function below takes `ntimes` as an argument which specifies the number of times you want to do the simulation.  It then uses `ggplot()` to make the graph.  You could adjust the internals of the function to have it produce a different looking plot if you like.

```
brownian <- function(T,N, ntimes){
  if((length(N) != length(T)) & length(N) != 1){
    stop("N has to be either length of T or 1\n")
  }
  alpha=0
  sigma=1
  if(length(N) == 1 & length(T) > 1)N <- rep(N, length(T))
  dat <- NULL
  for(i in 1:ntimes){
    delta_t=T/N  
    t=seq(0,T,by=delta_t)
    #x=c(0,alpha*delta_t+sigma*sqrt(delta_t)*rnorm(N,mean=0,sd=1))
    x=c(0,alpha*delta_t+sqrt(delta_t)*rnorm(N,mean=0,sd=1))
    Xt=cumsum(x)
    dat <- rbind(dat, data.frame(xt=Xt, t=t, n=i))
  }
  require(ggplot2)
  ggplot(dat, aes(x=t, y=xt, colour=as.factor(n))) + 
    geom_line(show.legend=FALSE) + 
    labs(x="t=[0,T]",y = "B(t,ω)", colour="T") + 
    theme_classic()
}
brownian(10,1000, 5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution with `matplot`. It is ideal for this type of plot, since it computes the x and y axis ranges and plots all lines in one call only. It uses [DaveArmstrong's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65494822/8245406) idea of adding an extra argument `ntimes`. This argument is also used for the color scheme.

```
brownian <- function(T, N, ntimes){
  alpha <- 0
  sigma <- 1
  delta_t <- T/N
  t <- seq(0, T, by = delta_t)
  #x=c(0,alpha*delta_t+sigma*sqrt(delta_t)*rnorm(N,mean=0,sd=1))
  Xt <- replicate(ntimes,
                  cumsum(c(0, alpha*delta_t+sqrt(delta_t)*rnorm(N, mean = 0, sd = 1)))
  )
  matplot(t, Xt, 
          type = "l", lty = 1, 
          col = seq_len(ntimes),
          xlab = "t=[0,T]", ylab = "B(t,ω)")
}

set.seed(2020)
brownian(1, 1000, 5)
```

[image]